# Writing equations in SQL using multiple variables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use data that is labeled by year (2012 - 2016) to calculate CAGR. The data was originally in one column indicating the total population with another column indicating the year. I've isolated the 2012 and 2016 data into two separate columns and am trying to use SQL to calculate the CAGR rate ((data from 2016)/(data from 2012)^(1/4))-1.

Is this the correct way to calculate CAGR/cummulative growth? I've tried simply using the two columns of data but because they are mismatched and have nulls, it doesn't work. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Compound Annual Growth Rate (CAGR) doesn't really lend itself to what you're trying to do.

Usually this is used when you say, invest $1000 in a fund, and you calculate the annual growth based on the ending value.

Example - if you invest $1000 and in 5 years it's worth $5000:

```
( 5,000 / 1,000)1/5 - 1 = .37973 = 37.97%
```

If I was to write that in SQL Server it would be:

```
SELECT SUM(POWER((5000.0/1000.0),(1.0/5.0))-1.0)
```

You can replace the 5000 and 1000 to be the specific columns you want to compare, or a range of data you need to compare.

If you elaborate your question I will update this answer.

Comment: Hi, I see that. I'm more so trying to use the CAGR as a way to show growth withing categories. I have for example, categories such as food, retail, etc and there is an employment number associated with each category and it is measured from 2012 to 2016. Thus, I am trying to pull the growth rate from these columns.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information for this then. As of now no one is able to assist you as we don't have the right informaiton

Comment: RE-Reading your comment I would suggest you update your question. Because you have categories that you want to have calculated.  Do these categories and values contain data from years 2013, 2014, 2015? because without that you'd not going to get a true CAGR

Comment: Hi, I do have data from years 2013, 2014, and 2015. My question is how do I get SQL to calculate growth over multiple years as it relates to growth in population if i have data about the population in each year. Thanks

Comment: These questions need to be mentioned in your original question, not in comments.